# How to fix the react-native-cli Failed to install the app error?

Tags: react-native

When i run the react-native run-android i face this error.
I tried to downgrade my java version to 8 but still not working.

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
    Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
    info JS server already running.
    info Installing the app...

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

    error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
    Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Task 'installDebug' not found in project ':app'.

    * Try:
    Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 3s

        at makeError (D:\freelance\SuperDaily\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
        at D:\freelance\SuperDaily\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
        at async runOnAllDevices (D:\freelance\SuperDaily\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
        at async Command.handleAction (D:\freelance\SuperDaily\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

Comment: run `react-native doctor` and check weather you have setup the ANDROID_HOME to local SDK folder

Answer (score 0):

I too got a similar error with this("node_modules/execa/index.js") file.
I resolved my error using the 2 commands given below

```sh
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

```sh
yarn global add @react-native-community/cli
```

If my solution doesn't work then check some other solutions [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/issues/80#issuecomment-536175565)

Answer (score 0):

```
react-native run-android --variant Huaweidebug
```

Run with above command.
it should fixed but in case error exists then open project in android studio